# asp.net how to make sure that the application close the file before closing

Tags: asp.net, xml, file

so I am currently working on a website in asp.net for my dynamic web desing class and I am working on the xml part right now. I currently have errors in my code and the application crash before reaching the fs.close(); wich close the file. When i try to run the debug again it crashes at the oppening of the file telling me that it is being used. I tried to close and open visual studio and my browser but the only thing that worked is rebooting my computer. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Post the code you used..

Comment: my question was not about why my code was crashing and it was solved.

Comment: You better close the file in a finaly clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I found that a process was remaining open : 
`WebDev.WebServer40.EXE *32` 
and if I kill it, I can now use the file again.